# Session variables lost between pages AFTER WEB SERVER MOVE shared to dedicated

Tags: php, session

I have just moved from a shared hosting package to a dedicated cloud server and uploaded my completely working website with session variables passing between pages just fine to the new dedicated server and now all of a sudden session variables are being lost. Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening?

I can supply some more code form the page if required but I figure this should suffice.

Also I did try setting a variable on a page then displaying it on the same page and that worked, but I don't if that value was even saved in the session as it was on the same page.

I know the versions of PHP have changed from 5.2.17(shared) to 5.3.3(dedicated) but I have tested this on my local machine with these different PHP versions and the session variables don't have any problems. Here's my two pages for you.

**page1.php**

```
<?php


session_start(); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['initiated']))
{
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['initiated'] = true;
}


include_once "header_selector.php";

$_SESSION['duper'] = "Active sessions variable";
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php

ob_start();

session_start(); 

include_once "header_selector.php";

$duper = $_SESSION['duper'];
echo "Model: " . $duper;
```

Comment: Have you checked your logs? Is your session_path writeable?

Comment: Have to tried with different web browser

Comment: Thanks for the replies. John I'm not sure how I would check? Vineet, I have not but will check.

Answer (score 0):

1) Odds are that your $_SESSION store isn't writable.

2) You're calling ob_start() without corresponding ob_end_flush(). You might have changed php.ini files when you moved hosts and PHP version and it is possible to screw that up with settings.

3) You're not calling ob_end_flush() in header_selector.php are you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sounds like your first suggestion to me. I do call the ob_flush at the end of page2.php and do not call the flush in header_selector.php. How would I go about allowing session store writing? Thanks.

Comment: call phpinfo(); and look for this configuration value: session.save_path.  That will tell you which directory that you're writing session data to. Make sure that the user *that the web server is running as* can read/write in that directory. You should see a ton of small-ish files there. (If the directory is not set, then you're using something else to store session data. Could be anything from memcache to MySQL. Same principals apply.) Do you have anything in your error logs of use? You really ought to if it's not writable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've looked at the information in phpinfo() and PHP sessions are being saved in this folder /var/lib/php/session however my site is in this folder /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/. Where there is also another folder /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/lib/php/ that has no 'session' folder. Should I be writing to that location?

I should mention that this site is currently in a /sitepreview/ folder on a dedicated cloud server atm.

Comment: The location is controlled by the session.* configuration values in your php.ini file. (You can also override some of those in code.) The location must be: writable by the web server's userid AND not the web site's directory structure (otherwise people could type URLs which could pull the $_SESSION data directly.)  Past that - it doesn't matter where you put it. It's commonly put in /tmp which has the added bonus of being cleaned out periodically.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, could I just ask. How would I go about making sure that the websites directory structure cannot write to the session location? I have this new dedicated(1and1) server and am worried that things like this will not have been protected against?

Thank you very much for your help.